# SPSS GENLINMIXED error

Tags: spss, mixed-models

I am examining 14-day diary data which involves a count outcome. The negative binomial with the log link seems to be the best fit for my data. When running the model in SPSS GENLINMIXED, I get the following error:

> glmm: Target data values for the negative binomial probability distribution must be non-negative integers.

However, I have confirmed that all my target values are non-negative integers. Has anyone seen this error message before, or have any idea where I might be going wrong?

In addition, even though the negative binomial is specified in the syntax, the output says the model distribution is "==& normal" - Does this mean that SPSS is using a normal distribution even though the syntax has specified the negative binomial? Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't seen this exact warning before, but I have seen a similar warning when I ran GENLINMIXED in SPSS (but with a binomial distribution and logit link). That error was "glmm: Valid values for events (target) and trials variables are non-negative and positive integers respectively, and the number of trials cannot be less than the number of events." I had my data set-up in long format and deleted the rows of data that had a missing response on the outcome (target) variable, and the warning disappeared. Maybe removing cases that have missing target data will work for you, too?